# accessing excel workbook in cloud with hyperlinks

Tags: microsoft-excel, pdf, sync, cloud-storage

I have an excel workbook that has hyperlinks to PDF documents. This workbook gets updated daily with new hyperlinks to documents.

I need to be able to have others access the excel document and be able to link the PDF documents by other members.

Only one person will be inserting new hyperlinks.

We need this workbook to be stored in the cloud, though either One Drive, Google Drive, in fact any cloud application free cloud application will work.

Issues we have run into trying this is that any new hyperlinks inserted are not showing in the workbook in the cloud.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Your question is vague and lacks details for anyone to help you. Is the person adding hyperlinks to the sheet adding them to the one in the cloud? How is the person editing the file? Details can be added by using the [edit] button under your question.

Comment: what do you mean by "cloud"? Is the file stored only in the cloud and opened in desktop Excel, or do you have issues when you try to open the hyperlinks from the file opened in browser (Excel, Google spreadsheet)? How hyperlinks are inserted (right click - hyperlink, or via hyperlink() function)?

Answer (score 0):

Either of the two services you mentioned are capable of the access control you are referring to. The way you would do it is to send the one editor an invite with write access and a second invite to all of the other users who will only have read access. As the owner of the document, you will be able to change this after the fact, but it is just as easy to set it with the invitation.

As it is an Excel file, I would suggest OneDrive as it gives you the ability to edit Excel spreadsheets within your web browser.

As for the document updating. You should see your changes if you update the cloud version of the document. As I mentioned above, you could go into OneDrive and update it directly.

If you want to work on it on your desktop, or needed to if you are running macros of VB scripts, then the way to do that is to install the **[OneDrive folder](https://onedrive.live.com/about/en-us/support/)** on your computer and save the file there. This way, as the document is changed, those changes should update when OneDrive syncs with your computer's (or the editor's) OneDrive folder.

If you choose the on computer option, then it is likely better to set up a folder for the document and share the folder with the users. You can give the same permissions as you would a file, but by doing this, if for some reason OneDrive does not associates edits with the shares but as a new document, they will still be able to see what is in that folder.